# What markup format does the VS Code C++ (Cpptools) extension support for rendering definition preview hovers?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I have seen this doc formatting comment in a library I added to one of my workspaces, and I see it uses something close to doxygen, and it works great off the shelf with VS code, I didn't install doxygen or any other doc generator plug in

```
  /**********************************************************************/
  /*!
    @brief  Apply the bracket's calibration curve to get a load in N from signal in mV
    @param  mV_reading    The loadcell's input signal in mV
  */
  /**********************************************************************/
    float _getTorqueNmFromBracketCurve(float mV_reading);
```

It works super well and generates nice doc when dragging over the function

[image]

Can someone point me to what is this doc and where I can find it's syntax documentation / arguments to learn to use it?

Comment: I believe this is the [Quick Info feature](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/cpp-ide#_quick-info) of the official C/C++ extension, although the documentation on the website is nearing two years old and they might have updated the feature a bit. I wasn't able to find any official syntax docs, but as you mentioned - it appears to be using a standard doxygen syntax.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Visual Studio** and **Visual Studio Code** recognize [**Doxygen**](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/visual-studio-code-c-extension-july-2020-update-doxygen-comments-and-logpoints/) comment formatting.

`/**`, `/*!` as well as `///`-style comments are supported.

There are also extensions that can [generate](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cschlosser.doxdocgen) doxygen comments.

Answer (score 5):

There are only some syntaxes that can be parsed by VSCode.

Reference: article by MS C++ Team: [C++ Team Blog - Visual Studio Code C++ Extension July 2020 Update: Doxygen comments and Logpoints](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/visual-studio-code-c-extension-july-2020-update-doxygen-comments-and-logpoints/)

```cpp
/// @brief Calculates the area of the triangle
/// @tparam T is the template param
/// @param base is the horizontal length
/// @param height is the vertical length
/// @return Area of triangle
/// @deprecated This is the deprecated comment
template<typename T>
T TriangleArea(T base, T height)
{
    double result;
    result = base * height * 0.5;
    return (T)result;
}
```

[image: imgur - doxygen VSCode visual picture]

There are lots of things VS C++ team can do.

Like:

- [GitHub issue - Can't specify newline](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/5741)
- [GitHub issue - Customizable Doxygen tags for Quick Info](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/8525)

Answer (score 0):

It supports a simple subset of Doxygen (see also https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/visual-studio-code-c-extension-july-2020-update-doxygen-comments-and-logpoints/). More recently, it also supports Markdown (see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/6020) (which is a kind of funny thing to be saying, since (to my understanding,) Markdown is already part of Doxygen's markup format).

Full docs for Doxygen's markup format can be found at https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html, with the caveat being that- as already stated- Doxygen support in Cpptools is partial- not full.

As with partial support things and newer features, there are things that aren't implemented (though might be in the future), and bugs, which you can find issue tickets about at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/labels/Feature%3A%20Doc%20comments.